# Merge [loop] and [looping] or make them more specific?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that there are two confusing tags: [loop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) and [looping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looping) and the latter has around twice the amount of questions.

It seems that both are used for questions on looping animations, code `loop` and shape/edge/face loops.

After discussing with Merlin, my suggestion is to make [looping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looping) for looping animation and create a specific tag for [edge-loop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edge-loop). Questions about code loops should have the [loop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) dropped and retagged as [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), [scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) or something else relevant, this is not a programming SE so there should not be specific coding tags.

I volunteer to help retagging the questions if someone approves the edits (or someone with higher rep could just do it more easily).

Comment: Code loops are basic flow control in programming, having a tag for them here would be redundant.  The more imperitive split would be between edge-loop and animation-loop. Depends on your philosophy, here's [Stack Overflow's tagging rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) which would suggest that anything with loop in it is a meta-tag

Comment: @Merlin According to the rules [edge-loop] would not be a meta-tag. The concept is different from a code loop and questions would benefit from this separation.

Comment: Yes, `edge-loop` is an operator in blender so it should exist.  I would argue that anything referring to code loops should be retagged `python`,`api` and `scripting` or similar and that `loop` be dropped as a reference to coding.

Comment: I can't do much until someone approves some of my edits / I gain more rep, but I'll try to at least fix the tags on the coding questions.